# WCF Latency Issue

Tags: wcf

I have a self hosted F# WCF Server that is used to return cached data to our application.  The amount of data can range from a single row to tens of thousands. Because of the large differences in data, I set the values in the app.config to handle a very large data items.  Everything was working fine until a week ago when something broke and the server just stopped working.  It took me a few days to get things and I never quite figured what was wrong.  I used the service utility and tweaked the settings till I got it working again.  The problem is that it has added 1.2 secs of latency that weren't there before.  I've tweaked the settings over and over and read every article I can find and nothing seems to help.  I have settings for both netTcp and Ws, but I'm using the netTcp settings.  (There may be some settings that don't need to be in there, but I wanted to put the whole thing here in case there are some conflicts that I'm unaware of.)
Here's the app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IPrevisionServer"  closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPrevisionServer" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="PrevisionSerializer"
       name="PrevisionServer.PrevisionService">
        <endpoint  address="net.tcp://192.168.101.100:2009/PrevisionService/tcp"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IPrevisionServer"
          contract="IPrevisionServer" name="NetTcpBinding_IPrevisionServer">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://192.168.101.100:2008/PrevisionService/ws/ws"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPrevisionServer" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceViewEventBehavior"
          contract="IPrevisionServer" name="WSHttpBinding_IPrevisionServer">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="ecloward@hcg" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.168.101.100:2009/PrevisionService/tcp" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceViewEventBehavior"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IPrevisionServer"
          contract="IPrevisionServer" name="NetTcpBinding_IPrevisionServer">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="ecloward@hcg" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HttpGetMetadata">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="PrevisionSerializer">
          <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="01:00:00" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000"
            maxConcurrentInstances="1000" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceViewEventBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="wcfTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="WcfClientTrace.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

I would like to use WCF, but in doing all this, it makes me wonder if maybe I should look at raw sockets instead?  Please let me know if there is other code that you want to see, but it's quite involved so I didn't want to post it all.

**UPDATE:** Per Richard Blewett, I'll explain what I'm trying to do and any guidance on the best way to configure this would be great.

Basically, I'm moving much of our business logic to an app server since much of it right now is contained in SQL Server stored procedures, and we're finding that due to the complexities of the queries, SQL is simply too slow.  By querying SQL, transforming the data using F# libraries on the app server and then caching it, I find that I'm able to drop times from 20-60 secs per request down to less than 3 after the data is cached, although most of that is due to the latency issue described above.  I know that 3 secs might be okay in some instances, but I know that it can go faster since it was working before, and eventually we want this be deployed on a cloud solution would then would involve 1000s of users, so I want this to be able to scale well.

The type of data what we're returning is generally going to be less than 10 columns, with each of those generally being strings of less than 100 chars or decimals.  But the data will have lots of rows, ranging from a few hundred to tens of thousands.  The number of clients will range from just a handful to possibly 100 or more at a time (although for the time being there are very few clients at this level).  The application that will be deployed on our various client sites, though will later be deployed in a cloud solution.

Since the data is mostly used for reporting, most of the calls are for read only data, hence the caching.  Usually a user runs a report, modifies a parameter, then runs the report again, so there will be call for a lot of data at once, then nothing for seconds or minutes.  There are some batch reporting processes though where a user will run a series of reports (often hundreds) in a row and therefore would be a large number of calls for data, again ranging from a few hundred rows to tens of thousands at a time.

I hope that this is enough to go on.  Thanks again!

Comment: Easy: Just pull the app.config that you used a week ago from version control and use that instead ;)

Comment: readerQuotas deal with XML handling. There is no need for such large values in all the attributes, especially maxDepth. You may also want to look into using messageEncoding="Mtom".

Comment: 500, I would but I didn't have the test client in version control. :(

Comment: @JimRhodes I've looked at MTom but every example I've seen uses streaming with files or images.  Is MTom something that can be used to send regular objects?  A link to a code sample would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If you're after speed remove all of the entries around WSHttpBinding - its just confusing matters.

MTOM is only beneficial if you are using textual XML to send binary in an interoperable way - you are using the binary encoder with NetTcpBinding so the data on the wire is already binary

I suspect you have turned on security in the service which was previously turned off which is where you see the performance difference.

Throwing config at a service may "get things working" but can cause big issues later. For example, you have set the receive timeout to an hour. This means that if a client does not close its proxy it will take an hour before your service decides that the client is not coming back and so it will maintain session resources for that client for an hour

If you detail what your requirements are in terms of timeouts, message sizes and security then we can help you get a configuration that matches your requirements

Comment: Richard, thanks for your time in working on this.  I have added the description above.  Please let me know if there is anything else that you need.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Erick - I quick calculation shows you could be returning 40Mb of data - are you sure the dataset you are returning hasn't recently grown - thus changing the performance profile? Otherwise - what are your security requirements? Does the data need to be encrypted?

Comment: Richard - The test data has remained the same.  The data does not need to be encrypted, at least not now.  There will be a default user calling from the client app so not worried about AD or anything like that.

Comment: If you set `<security mode="None"/>` on the binding do you see your throughput increase again?

Comment: Richard - No change.  I'm pretty sure I had it that way before, so no surprise.

Comment: Could you add another method that moves no data and check the timing of that - then we can check whether its the overhead of the call or the data that is causing your latency? Also is it every call or just the first one through a proxy - are subsequent calls faster?

Comment: Richard, I have an Add method that takes two ints that has doesn't have latency, so it is isolated to the larger data.  I'm just frustrated because it was working so well before.  Also, I'm testing this on my dev quad core/16 GB RAM machine, so the app server and the client are both on my computer.  Any other ideas for adjusting configurations?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7504/discussion-between-erick-and-richard-blewett)